# Is it possible to add an IE conditional statement to an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-7, gmail, conditional-statements

I'm trying to send an email, and for no reported bug fix out there can solve a margin error I am finding. I might be on the brilliant beginning of something never before seen by the web developer community! ;)

So I'm trying to write a IE conditional statement such as :

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
%img.header-left{:src => "http://hqchannel.com/images/me-header-left.jpg", :style => "height: 498px; width: 110px; display: block; float: left;"}
<![endif]-->
```

But this is read ( by gmail ), as just commented out HTML, and it is not parsed whatsoever no matter what browser I am using.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible, but it's still a good question!

Comment: Well f@#$. :D Where's willy wonka when you need him.

Comment: Outlook 2007/2010 use Word to render HTML emails and not IE.  I found this a helpful resource in seeing what limited HTML/CSS is supported by various email clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

We cheated by adding a strip of white on the left to the image itself!

Answer (score 1):

Email renderers are very simple, and as (more?) varied than web browsers, their HTML support is usually not very robust.

Thus you should invoke 1990's HTML styles: Tables and spacer images. Or as you'll notice many marketing campaigns do - mosaic images. The simpler your email the more consistently it will render.